# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier forIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a custom/sub-classed UITableViewCell using NSLayoutConstraints. The left most UIImageView may or may not be populated with an image, and if not, the objects to right of this field will naturally shift to the left. Works well within the custom UITableViewCell, however I'll be populating the content with my custom UITableViewController. Unfortunately, following code will populate every row cell.dispatchedView with an image -- though I've trapped to not populate rows with anything.

This has something to do with the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. Ideas?

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[NXGActiveUnitsCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *item = [self.model.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NXGActiveUnitsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if([[[item objectForKey:@"cfs_no"] clean] length] > 0) {
        cell.dispatchedView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"p.png"];
        NSLog(@">>>%@",[item objectForKey:@"cfs_no"] );
    } else {
        NSLog(@">>> i got nothing so I should not touch this row...");
    }

    cell.departmentIconView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"f.png"];
    cell.unitLabel.text = [item valueForKey:@"unit_id"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the "else" part of your if-else statement is never entered? If so, you need to add some more code to show what self.model looks like.

Comment: Actually, the 'else' is entered. When I scroll down the tableView I see the log enter ">>> i got nothing so I should not touch this row...", yet I see the image "p.png" in the row. If I comment out the if statement, I do not see the "p.png" in any row. I'm baffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this already solves your problem, but you should
definitely set

```
cell.dispatchedView.image = nil;
```

in the else-case, because cells are reused.