# IBOutlet of UITableViewCell subview is (NULL)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, iboutlet

I have a custom UITableViewCell defined in a xib.  It has two views in its Content View, a label and a text view.

In my table view controller, using either

```
JJDTextInputCell *cell = [[SDLTextInputCell alloc] init];
```

or

```
JJDTextInputCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TextInputCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

the IBOutlet is null, so the table view does not show the default text or any text I try to display using

```
cell.descriptionLabel.text = @"foo";
```

What is the proper way to initialize custom UITableView cells created using interface builder?

Comment: i think what you want is load a custom cell in table view from xib. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize them from xib file.

```
JJDTextInputCell *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JJDTextInputCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there are two ways to dequeue table cell, you can find them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:) in the doc. Find them under `Creating Table View Cells`. You are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` which always returns a valid cell BUT you need to use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` function in pair with this. You have to register the class and then you will get a valid cell. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292256/dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-forindexpath) question for reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using XIB for custom cell you should use

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:"CellIdentifier"];
```

for registering a cell instead of

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[TableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:"CellIdentifier"];
```